# Local path URI in C# WPF

Tags: c#, uri, relative-path, absolute-path

If I use an open file dialog box that returns the absolute value of the file this works just fine:

```
  BMP = new BitmapImage(new Uri(filename));
```

However, I want to have a text file that contains the names of the files, like this:

```
01TopographicalMap.bmp
01ElevationCompressed.elv
01Terrain.trn
01Placenames.pns
```

These files are loaded sequentially. Unfortunately, the previous Uri(filename) call barfs because it wants the whole absolute path. We're already in the same folder. What do I have to do to get the Uri to just default to the folder it's already in?

Thanks, for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`

Or:

> Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), filename);